# Unknown type name AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm currently going through [this tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-16-populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-the-web/). I've installed AFNetworking but when I put in this code I get errors on lines 7 and 8 saying `Unknown type name AFJSONRequestOperation` and `No known class method for selector JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request`.

```
-(void)makeRestuarantRequests
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"A URL which returns JSON"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
//AFNetworking asynchronous url request
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                            JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                            success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"JSON RESULT %@", responseObject);

                                     }
                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                            NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];

[operation start];

}
```

It seems that I have a file missing that contains a class that I need, perhaps a `AFJSONRequestOperation.m` and `.h`.

Any ideas for a fix?

**EDIT:**

All `.h` files in the original [AFNetworking download](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/AFNetworking) have been imported via `AFNetworking.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef _AFNETWORKING_
    #define _AFNETWORKING_

    #import "AFURLRequestSerialization.h"
    #import "AFURLResponseSerialization.h"
    #import "AFSecurityPolicy.h"
    #import "AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h"

    #import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"
    #import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
    #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"


#if ( ( defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 1090) || \
      ( defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000 ) )
    #import "AFURLSessionManager.h"
    #import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
#endif

#endif /* _AFNETWORKING_ */
```

Comment: You've missed an `#import`...

Comment: All these files are imported: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/AFNetworking As I said, there must be something missing

Comment: All of them?  Sounds a bit overkill.

Comment: Take a look at my edit

Comment: I didn't notice `AFJSONRequestOperation.h`.

Comment: No, it's not on the list I linked to although it looks like it should be...

Answer (score 1):

Which version of `AFNetworking` are you using? Seems like you are using version 2.x, and `AFJSONRequestOperation` is from version 1.x.

See also here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the OP Im guessing but I had this problem because there was two copies of `AFNetworking` floating around the source folder. One in my `CocoaPods` install and one from earlier on which hadn't been deleted.

I discovered this by searching for "AFNetworking" in the compile command output of the error message which showed me a copy of AFNetworking that I wasn't expecting.

Dumping the non-pod copy fixed it all up.

Answer (score -1):

add System.Configuration framework. Then add
 #import  in pch. Maybe the problem occurs from the Configuration framework.